Hibernate many-to-many relation with extra column returns NonUniqueObjectException when adding a relation
I am running into an error when trying to update a many to many relation between users and teams. I have pretty much followed the blog from Vlad explaining how the model should be implemented. I am using the latest version of Springboot (3.2.4) and hence one of the latest version of Hibernate and Java 17. I loaded everything eagerly, as this is not the focus of my issue. Here are the my entities (not the complete classes to make it more readable):
UserEntity:
public class UserEntity {

    public UserEntity(String loginName) {
        this.loginName = loginName;
    }

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "login_name")
    private String loginName;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<UserTeamEntity> teams = new HashSet<>();

    public void addTeam(TeamEntity team, boolean isTeamLeader, boolean isPrimaryTeam) {
        Optional<UserTeamEntity> optionalUserTeam = teams.stream().filter(userTeamEntity -> userTeamEntity.getTeam().equals(team))
                .findFirst();

        if (optionalUserTeam.isPresent()) {
            optionalUserTeam.get().setTeamLeader(isTeamLeader);
            optionalUserTeam.get().setUserPrimaryTeam(isPrimaryTeam);
        } else {
            UserTeamEntity userTeamEntity = new UserTeamEntity(this, team, isTeamLeader, isPrimaryTeam);
            teams.add(userTeamEntity);
            team.getUserTeams().add(userTeamEntity);
        }
    }

    Set<UserTeamEntity> getUserTeams() {
        return teams;
    }

TeamEntity
public class TeamEntity {

    public TeamEntity(String displayName) {
        this.id = null;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.users = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "display_name")
    private String displayName;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "team",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<UserTeamEntity> users = new HashSet<>();

    public void addUser(UserEntity userEntity, boolean isPrimaryTeam, boolean isLeader) {
        Optional<UserTeamEntity> optionalUserTeam = users.stream().filter(userTeamEntity -> userTeamEntity.getUser().equals(userEntity))
                .findFirst();

        if (optionalUserTeam.isPresent()) {
            optionalUserTeam.get().setTeamLeader(isLeader);
            optionalUserTeam.get().setUserPrimaryTeam(isPrimaryTeam);
        } else {
            UserTeamEntity userTeamEntity = new UserTeamEntity(userEntity, this, false, false);
            users.add(userTeamEntity);
            userEntity.getUserTeams().add(userTeamEntity);
        }
    }

    Set<UserTeamEntity> getUserTeams() {
        return users;
    }

}

UserTeamEntity
public class UserTeamEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserTeamId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("userLoginName")
    private UserEntity user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("teamId")
    private TeamEntity team;

    @Column(name = "is_team_leader")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    private boolean isTeamLeader = false;

    @Column(name = "is_user_primary_team")
    @Convert(converter = YesNoConverter.class)
    private boolean isUserPrimaryTeam = false;

    public UserTeamEntity(UserEntity user, TeamEntity team, boolean isTeamLeader, boolean isUserPrimaryTeam) {
        this.id = new UserTeamId(user.getLoginName(), team.getId());
        this.user = user;
        this.team = team;
        this.isTeamLeader = isTeamLeader;
        this.isUserPrimaryTeam = isUserPrimaryTeam;
    }

}

When adding a user to the team (or the other way around) in an integration test and updating the team (4th step in the WHEN part), I get the error Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.UserTeamEntity#com.example.UserTeamId]
    @Test
    void updateTeamService() {
        // GIVEN
        TeamEntity team = createTeam(TEAM_DISPLAY_NAME);
        createUser(USER_LOGIN_NAME);

        // WHEN
        TeamEntity teamToUpdate = userTeamService.findById(team.getId());
        UserEntity userToAdd = userTeamService.findById(USER_LOGIN_NAME);
        teamToUpdate.addUser(userToAdd, false, false);
        userTeamService.updateTeam(teamToUpdate);

        // THEN
        TeamEntity updatedEntity = userTeamService.findById(team.getId());
        assertEquals(1, updatedEntity.getAllUsers().size());
        assertTrue(updatedEntity.getAllUsers().stream().anyMatch(user -> USER_LOGIN_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getLoginName())));
    }

For a full reproducible example, you can have a look at one of my github repository
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am really confused why this does not work.
What I have tried or investigated so far:

I have tried to dig into hibernate and follow the origin of the error, but I simply do not understand why UserTeamId has different objects associated with the session. It seems like hibernate is creating its own instance of the object before persisting it!.
I also made sure that I did not do things vastly differently than in the blog I was following.
The code above is also a minimal sample from a much bigger project, so that I can try to isolate the issue, but it did not help me.


In the method addUser() of TeamEntity class you are adding the new UserTeamEntity instance in the users and in the userEntity.getUserTeams()  persistent sets. Hibernate records this as two new entities, and when you try to persist the TeamEntity entity, it detects that it must persist two entities with the same primary key, and then raises the exception.
You must adapt your code in a way that the UserTeamEntity is not in the two sets when you persist the entities.

Thank you for your answer!
I removed team.getUserTeams().add(userTeamEntity); and indeed it seems to work. I thought though when adding an entity in a relation that I needed to add on both sides of the relationship (like it is explaining in the blog) ?

In your updateTeam() method you use the @Transactional attribute. This means that everything you do in the entities inside this method is persisted at the end of the method, even if you don't call repository.save(). The teams and the users are persisted, including the two persistent sets. In the referenced blog, the entitymanager and hibernate session are used but not in a transaction, and only the Post entities are persisted. This means that only the Post persistent set of PostTag is persisted, but not the User entities and its PostTag persistent sets, preventing duplication.

I have cloned your github project. If I launch the test as it is, the test fails raising the exception, but if I remove the @Transaction attribute of the updateTeam() method, the test passes. This confirms what I've said in the last comment.

Okay, thank you. What you wrote makes sense for my use case, and it indeed works as you described.
Though, I still don't understand why hibernate decides to save the same object present in the two persistent set (but with the same reference) as two separate entities. I could not find any documentation either regarding that particular case.

I will mark your answer as the accepted one as it answers directly my use case. Thank you for your help!
